# __NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count: crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
queryParams = @{@"geo_location" : [GlobalData sharedGlobalData].latLong, @"sale_ids": selectedSaleId};
```

It sometimes crashes on the live app, but we cannot reproduce the crash. I've been trying to analyze the report and understand what might be the cause of the crash, but I haven't been successful.

I would like some help understanding under what circumstances the following crash would occur:

```
1 __exceptionPreprocess + 1245624
2 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 34136
3    CoreFoundation    -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 81576
4    CoreFoundation    +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 81176
5    MyApp    -[SaleViewController loadStores] (SaleViewController.m:378)
6    MyApp    -[SaleViewController viewDidLoad](SaleViewController.m:158)
7    UIKit    -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 63776
8    UIKit    -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 160944
9    UIKit    -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1766832
10   UIKit    -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 818800
11    UIKit    -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 817880
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the crash looks like when one of the values placed in a collection is nil.  You can defend against this crash with a conditional:

```
if ([GlobalData sharedGlobalData].latLong && selectedSaleId) {
    queryParams = @{@"geo_location" : [GlobalData sharedGlobalData].latLong, @"sale_ids": selectedSaleId};
}
```

Either that, or the debugging task at hand is to find out why either value was nil.